# Git push of large file cannot be completed

Tags: github, large-files, git-push

I'm trying to push some work to Github but the pushing process never got completed. It took a long time to process and I got this error at the end. My guess is because the mp4 video I put in is too heavy. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
git push --set-upstream origin my-branch
Enumerating objects: 141, done.
Counting objects: 100% (141/141), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
Writing objects: 100% (104/104), 152.71 MiB | 15.78 MiB/s, done.
Total 104 (delta 76), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (76/76), completed with 30 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: 3b2ffa824df43ed5263541b5d402f5c2c69aafabbdd8a21c5836fd4c02416ea3
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File src/assets/videos/introduction.mp4 is 107.64 MB; this exceeds 
GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/projectname/projectname.git
 ! [remote rejected] projectname -> projectname (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/projectname/projectname.git'
```

Comment: You should try to avoid pushing assets to git. Git is a tool to maintain a code base, not assets.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error:

```
File src/assets/videos/introduction.mp4 is 107.64 MB; this exceeds 
GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

You could look into [GitHub LFS](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/configuring-git-large-file-storage) or you can use something like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to compress it to under 100MB, I'd personally go with the latter.

Comment: So, I used Handbrake to compress the video, deleted the mp4 video and put in compressed video (m4v file) instead. but when I git add, git commit, then git push again, it still shows the same error with the mp4 file. I'm not sure what really happening here.

Comment: this is due to the previous commit and I do not know how to get rid of that

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. one way is to follows the link that git showed us. (http://git.io/iEPt8g). Another solution is if you do not want to add that video to the git repository then delete that video or larger file from repository folder.
After that use command

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

This will take you back to one step behind. To go back to N number of steps follow the following command:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~N
```

That's all do your git commit and push your data without that larger file or video to git.